# @AspectJ syntax for "after() : staticinitialization(*)"

Tags: java, aspectj, aspects, static-initialization

I'm trying to implement a tracing aspect using the **pertypewithin** instantiation model.
In this way, I'll be able to use one logger per class per type.

From some examples arround the we I can find this code to init the logger:

```
public abstract aspect TraceAspect pertypewithin(com.something.*) {
    abstract pointcut traced();
    after() : staticinitialization(*) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(getWithinTypeName());
    }
    before() : traced() {
        logger.log(...);
    }
    //....
}
```

unfortunately, I'm not able to fully translate this to the @AspectJ syntax (it's a project requirement outside my control), especially the part in with I need to setup the logger, executing that code only once.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Aspect("pertypewithin(com.something.*))")
public abstract class TraceAspect {

Logger logger;

@Pointcut
public abstract void traced();

@Pointcut("staticinitialization(*)")
public void staticInit() {
}

@After(value = "staticInit()")
public void initLogger(JoinPoint.StaticPart jps) {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(jps.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
}

@Before(value = "traced()")
public void traceThatOne(JoinPoint.StaticPart jps) {
    logger.log(jps.getSignature().getName());
}
}
```

Comment: I had tried that before posting the question, unsuccessfully. But after you answer I decided to come back to this approach and I figured out that the real issue was with a code that generated a stack overflow (no pun intended)... now it's solved. Thanks again!

Comment: Perfect answer, uses annotations too which is the preferred notation for AspectJ 5 onwards. Thank you :-)

Comment: @KomodoDave, I was just wondering: why do you say that annotations are the preferred notation for AspectJ 5 onwards? I find the annotation syntax to *define* aspects (as used above) to be more difficult, since the string expressions in the annotations' attributes are not parsed until runtime. Using the native AspectJ syntax along with ajc is less verbose and it's compile-time checked, which obviously catches things *much* earlier than runtime. Now, I *do* think it's nice to use annotations in defining your pointcuts, as a developer can see the annotation as a visual indication that something s

Comment: @MatthewAdams AspectJ weaves at compile-time or load-time, not at runtime. As stated [here](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html) _"AspectJ 5 does not provide explicit support for run-time weaving"_. You can only create runtime weaving if you use Spring proxy AOP support. As for my stating annotations are "preferred" - I misspoke, and should have said "..is *my* preferred notation..". Annotation vs non-annotation approaches each offer features the other does not. It comes down to personal preference. My preference is to use Annotations because I consider AOP metadata.