# AspectJ staticinitalization

Tags: aspectj, aop

i'm successfully intercepting the static initialization of classes with @MyAnnotation with this code:

```
public aspect SomeAspect {
    pointcut printClassName() : staticinitialization(@MyAnnotation *);
    after() : printClassName() {
        System.out.println(getClass().getName());        
    }
}
```

The question is: how do i get the name of the loaded class? In the code above what's printed is the name of the aspect class, not the name of the loaded class.

Thanks,
Teo

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382464/aspectj-syntax-for-after-staticinitialization) for the start of the solution--I'm more familiar with the annotation approach than the AspectJ language, but basically you need the join point's signature, or the withinTypeName value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **thisJoinPoint** to get these type of information. This code does the trick.

```
    after(): printClassName(){
         System.out.println(thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    }
```