# AspectJ - Creating a global Logger field using an Inter-Type Declaration

Tags: eclipse, class, logging, global, aspectj

I'd like to create an Inter-Type declaration that declares a (static final) Logger instance inside each class.

The constructor should be passed the enclosing class `Klazz.class` value:

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggerAspect {

    public interface Logger {
    }

    public static class LoggerImpl implements Logger {
        private static final Logger logger = 
          new Logger(thisJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass()/*.getName()*/);
    }

    @DeclareParents(value="com.my.api..*",defaultImpl=LoggerImpl.class)
    private Logger implementedInterface;
}
```

I wrote the above solution, however I'm unable to use `thisJoinPoint` outside of an AspectJ `advice`.

If the Logger default implementation is applied to some class Klazz, how can I modify the above code to successfully pass Klazz.class to the Logger constructor?

Comment: My answer (which you accepted) also shows the correct solution. I just had not declared the logger variable in my initial code snippet, because I thought it was trivial. As for the preferred notation, I think this is mainly a matter of taste. I much prefer the native AspectJ notation because to me it seems to be so much clearer and more expressive than the Java + annotation vehicle. Furthermore, in Eclipse I like the syntax hightlighting and code completion when working with AspectJ. So it really is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 7):

You can declare a static member on any single class via inter-type declaration:

```java
public aspect LoggingAspect {
    static Logger MyClass.someField = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
}
```

But this is not very flexible because you need to do it for each single class. I just wanted to mention it.

In order to add something which is not technically but effectively a static member to a class, just use per-type association for your logging aspect:

```java
public aspect LoggingAspect
    pertypewithin(org.foo..*)              // per-type association
{
    Logger logger;

    after() : staticinitialization(*) {    // run 1x after class-loading
        logger = Logger.getLogger(
            getWithinTypeName()            // type associated with aspect instance
        );
    }

    pointcut logged() :                    // what to log, e.g. public methods
        execution(public * *(..));         // (pointcut could also be abstract
                                           // and refined in sub-aspects)

    before() : logged() {
        logger.log(...);                   // logging action
    }
}
```

An example similar to this one - it is a common pattern - can be found in Ramnivas Laddad's excellent book [AspectJ in action (2nd edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988053), chapter 6.2.4. It is also mentioned in the [AspectJ documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/pertypewithin.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response, kriegaex. How is the 'logger' field defined in the above. Does using pertypewithin as you've exemplified require declaring the field manually in all classes, albeit uninitialised?

Comment: [This answer to an equivalent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382464/aspectj-syntax-for-after-staticinitialization) gave me an annotation-based solution that follows approximately what you said, but also creates a logger field as I would expect.

Comment: In my answer I wanted to concentrate on the most important stuff. But I have added the missing logger declaration now. I did not expect its missing would cause difficulty in understanding for you. The logger is an instance variable of the aspect, by the way.

Comment: Thank you - you have to be exlicit in an explanation because although I've read a lot about AspectJ, it's a complicated technique to grok and for all I know the contruct you'd defined may create a Logger field automatically - it's entirely arbitrary depending on the AspectJ spec and implementation. Anyway, I appreciate the clarification.

Comment: For others viewing - this answer is a valid solution, however consult the answer I linked to in my second comment to this answer for an annotation-based version, which is the more modern standard to use.

Comment: I disagree: It is not more modern, just different. I fail to see why cramming the AOP paradigm into an OOP concept like annotations should be more modern than using a more expressive language like AspectJ specifically designed to do AOP. Both approaches are valid, please stop disqualifying one of them just because you do not like it.

Comment: AspectJ annotations are more modern; they were introduced recently into AspectJ presumably because the developers seek more standardised markup. Annotations are a standard Java feature and consequently sit nicer with syntax highlighters and auto-indentation, and also offer more intuitive understanding for Java developers. Non-java keywords present problems when using any Java editor, as opposed to an ActiveJ editor like that integrated in Eclipse. I have seen many libraries convert from bespoke markup to use Annotations for these and other benefits.

Comment: Introduced later != more modern. But let us stop discussing this matter. I am happy your problem is solved and you even found someone who expressed it in a syntax more familiar to you than the native AspectJ I prefer. Let's each one of us keep his own pet without disqualifying the other one's, will you?

Comment: Annotations have only recently been added to AspectJ; they are implicitly modern. This community is based on identifying the "best" solution for the problem, considering (i) ease of understanding, (ii) usability, (iii) efficiency, (iv) adherence to coding standards. In the Java community it is considered "best" to use annotations rather than non-standard markup [see (iv)]. I have therefore indicated what I think the "best" answer is, and am not heeding your comments which from my perspective attempt to covet your answer rather than objectively consider the "best" solution.

Comment: So after you have accepted my initial answer and even acknowledge its being correct by editing your question, you now un-accept it just because I disagree with you about wether it is "more modern" or just different? How unfair is that? Thank you for making it really "worthwhile" to take the trouble to answer and discuss details with you.

Comment: And as for coding standards: You have tagged your question "aspectj" by yourself, so please don't be surprised if  I provide an answer in AspectJ syntax.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382464/aspectj-syntax-for-after-staticinitialization) gives the correct solution, posted below for convenience. Additionally it uses AspectJ annotations which is the preferred notation nowadays.

The developers recently added the annotation API, I presume with the intention of standardising the markup as many other popular libraries like Spring are also doing.

```java
@Aspect("pertypewithin(com.something.*))")
public abstract class TraceAspect {

    Logger logger;

    @Pointcut
    public abstract void traced();

    @Pointcut("staticinitialization(*)")
    public void staticInit() {
    }

    @After(value = "staticInit()")
    public void initLogger(JoinPoint.StaticPart jps) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(jps.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName());
    }

    @Before(value = "traced()")
    public void traceThatOne(JoinPoint.StaticPart jps) {
        logger.log(jps.getSignature().getName());
    }
}
```