# AspectJ - Static inter-type declaration on classes implementing a given interface

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I would like to know if it is possible (and how if it is...) to make a static inter-type declaration that works on all classes that implements a given interface.

In my use case, I have an empty interface:

```
public interface Delegate {}
```

and two classes implementing it:

```
public class DelegateA implements Delegate {...}
public class DelegateB implements Delegate {...}
```

And I want an aspect to declare a static member on DelegateA and DelegateB... and all the future classes that will implements my interface !

How should I do it ? If it's only possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to do that? In any case, here is my best solution for your problem:

```
public aspect MyAspect pertypewithin(Delegate+){
    public int oneFieldPerClass;
}
```

This will instantiate an aspect for each subtype of Delegate. You can access the field in the following ways:

```
MyAspect.aspectOf(DelegateA.class).oneFieldPerClass = 1;
MyAspect.aspectOf(DelegateB.class).oneFieldPerClass = 2;

Delegate d = new DelegateA(); 
MyAspect.aspectOf(d.getClass()).onFieldPerClass = 3;
```

The following thread might be helpful as well:

[AspectJ - Creating a global Logger field using an Inter-Type Declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126436/aspectj-creating-a-global-logger-field-using-an-inter-type-declaration)

HTH, dsp