# Apply aspectj on complete package rather than on a particular class

Tags: java, log4j, aspectj, logback

How to apply aspectj on complete package rather than on a particular class?

My code is like this

```
public abstract aspect BasicLogModel {

ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger = (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(ModArc.class);

pointcut greeting() : execution(* Model.ModArc*(..));

// this function will work before any function execution
before() : greeting() {
    }
}
```

using this code logger will come for only ModArc class but i need logger for complete package which is Model here what changes I need to made Please give some suggestions.

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Atm I cannot test what I wrote down but I would write something like this

```
execution(* Model..*(..))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried like this But unfortunately its not working means in logger we have given ModArc.class so that its taking only ModArc class.

Answer (score 0):

There's what I use to log every method call in org.example.batch package. Note the '..' it might be(or not) useful for you

```
execution(* org.example.batch..*.*(..))
```

[The ".." wildcard matches any sequence of characters that start and end with a ".", so it can be used to pick out all types in any subpackage, or all inner types](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html)
UPDATE: if you're trying to implement logging solution based on aspectj - it's already [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126436/aspectj-creating-a-global-logger-field-using-an-inter-type-declaration).